# how to Convert Numeric value to Indian Rupees words in Sql ..?

Tags: sql

how to Convert Numeric value to Indian Rupees words in Sql ..?

Comment: Better explanation please! Examples etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[NumberToWordsNew]    Script Date: 04/02/2015 18:45:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[NumberToWordsNew] (@intNumberValue INTEGER)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
AS  
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @strNumberString VARCHAR(9)
  DECLARE @strReturn VARCHAR(2000)
  DECLARE @intUnits SMALLINT

  -- Create table of number groups  
  DECLARE @tblNumberGroups TABLE (Units SMALLINT, Hundreds SMALLINT, Tens SMALLINT)

   -- Handle errors and 'quick wins' 
  IF @intNumberValue IS NULL RETURN NULL
  IF ISNUMERIC(@intNumberValue)=0 RETURN NULL
  IF @intNumberValue = 0 RETURN 'ZERO'  

  IF @intNumberValue < 0
  BEGIN
    SET @strReturn='MINUS '
    SET @intNumberValue=ABS(@intNumberValue)
  END

  SET @intUnits =0

  -- Populate table of number groups  
  WHILE (@intNumberValue % 1000) > 0 OR  (@intNumberValue/1000) >0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tblNumberGroups (Units, Hundreds, Tens) VALUES (@intUnits, (@intNumberValue % 1000)/100, (@intNumberValue % 1000) % 100 )
    SELECT @intNumberValue = CAST (@intNumberValue / 1000 AS INTEGER)
    SET @intUnits = @intUnits + 1
  END

  -- Remove last unit added
  SET @intUnits = @intUnits-1  

  -- Concatenate text number by reading number groups in reverse order
  SELECT @strReturn = ISNULL(@strReturn,' ') +
  ISNULL(
  ISNULL((CASE Hundreds
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ONE HUNDRED '
    WHEN 2 THEN 'TWO HUNDRED '
    WHEN 3 THEN 'THREE HUNDRED '
    WHEN 4 THEN 'FOUR HUNDRED '
    WHEN 5 THEN 'FIVE HUNDRED '
    WHEN 6 THEN 'SIX HUNDRED '
    WHEN 7 THEN 'SEVEN HUNDRED '
    WHEN 8 THEN 'EIGHT HUNDRED '
    WHEN 9 THEN 'NINE HUNDRED '
  END),' ') + 
  CASE WHEN (Hundreds >0 OR Units<@intUnits) AND Tens > 0   THEN ' AND ' ELSE ' ' END +
  ISNULL((CASE Tens / 10
    WHEN 2 THEN 'TWENTY '
    WHEN 3 THEN 'THIRTY '
    WHEN 4 THEN 'FORTY '
    WHEN 5 THEN 'FIFTY '
    WHEN 6 THEN 'SIXTY '
    WHEN 7 THEN 'SEVENTY '
    WHEN 8 THEN 'EIGHTY '
    WHEN 9 THEN 'NINETY '
  END),' ') +
  ISNULL((CASE Tens
    WHEN 10 THEN 'TEN '
    WHEN 11 THEN 'ELEVEN '
    WHEN 12 THEN 'TWELVE '
    WHEN 13 THEN 'THIRTEEN '
    WHEN 14 THEN 'FOURTEEN '
    WHEN 15 THEN 'FIFTEEN '
    WHEN 16 THEN 'SIXTEEN '
    WHEN 17 THEN 'SEVENTEEN '
    WHEN 18 THEN 'EIGHTEEN '
    WHEN 19 THEN 'NINETEEN '
  END),' ') +
  COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN Tens %10 =1 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'ONE ' END,
    CASE WHEN Tens %10 =2 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'TWO ' END,
  CASE WHEN Tens %10 =3 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'THREE ' END,
  CASE WHEN Tens %10 =4 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'FOUR ' END,
    CASE WHEN Tens %10 =5 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'FIVE ' END,
    CASE WHEN Tens %10 =6 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'SIX ' END,
    CASE WHEN Tens %10 =7 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'SEVEN ' END,
    CASE WHEN Tens %10 =8 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'EIGHT ' END,
    CASE WHEN Tens %10 =9 AND Tens / 10  <> 1 THEN 'NINE ' END,
  ' ')+
  COALESCE(
   CASE WHEN Units=1 AND (Hundreds>0 OR Tens>0) THEN 'THOUSAND ' END,
    CASE WHEN Units=2 AND (Hundreds>0 OR Tens>0) THEN 'MILLION ' END,
   CASE WHEN Units=3 AND (Hundreds>0 OR Tens>0) THEN 'BILLION ' END,
   CASE WHEN Units=4 AND (Hundreds>0 OR Tens>0) THEN 'TRILLION ' END,
  ' ')
   ,' ')
  FROM @tblNumberGroups
  ORDER BY units DESC

  -- Get rid of all the spaces 
  WHILE CHARINDEX('  ', @strReturn)>0
   BEGIN
      SET @strReturn = REPLACE(@strReturn,'  ',' ')
   END

  SET @strReturn = LTRIM(RTRIM(@strReturn))

  RETURN @strReturn
END


/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[DSP_NumericToRupees]    Script Date: 04/02/2015 18:43:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DSP_NumericToRupees]( @RUPEES AS DECIMAL(30,2))

RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)

AS

BEGIN



DECLARE @INNTBL_01 TABLE (RECNO INT IDENTITY(1, 1), MTEXT NVARCHAR(50))

DECLARE @INNTBL_02 TABLE (RECNO INT IDENTITY(1, 1), MTEXT NVARCHAR(50))

DECLARE @AMOUNT NUMERIC(38,0)

DECLARE @PAISE AS INT

SET @AMOUNT = FLOOR(@RUPEES)




SET @PAISE =   CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,0),(@RUPEES % 1) * 100  ) AS INT)


--STEP 2:

--NOW ADD UP THE SALT AND PEPPER ONTO TABLE  I.E. INSERT THE WORDS INTO IT

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'One '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Two '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Three '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Four '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Five '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Six '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Seven '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Eight '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Nine '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Ten '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Eleven '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Twelve '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Thirteen '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Fourteen '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Fifteen '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Sixteen '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Seventeen '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Eighteen '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Nineteen '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_01 SELECT 'Twenty '

-- SIMILARY, INSERT THE MULTIPLES

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Ten '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Twenty '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Thirty '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Forty '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Fifty '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Sixty '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Seventy '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Eighty '

INSERT INTO @INNTBL_02 SELECT 'Ninety '

--STEP 3:

----CHECK FOR THE LIMIT OF THE AMOUNT I.E. WHAT IS THE PLACE VALUE OF DIGITS -- LACS, THOUSANDS OR HUNDREDS

DECLARE @WORD VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @WORD = ''

DECLARE @M_AMT01  BigInt, @M_AMT02 BigInt

IF  @AMOUNT >= 10000000 BEGIN

SET @M_AMT01 = @AMOUNT

SELECT @AMOUNT = ( @AMOUNT % 10000000 )



SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01-@AMOUNT ) / 10000000

DECLARE @WORD1 VARCHAR(300)

SET @WORD1 = ''

--IF @M_AMT01 < 100 AND @M_AMT01 > 20 BEGIN

--SET @M_AMT02 = @M_AMT01

--SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01 % 10)

--SET @M_AMT02 = ( @M_AMT02-@M_AMT01 ) / 10

--SET @WORD1 = ( SELECT @WORD1 + MTEXT FROM @INNTBL_02 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT02 )

--END






IF @M_AMT01 <= 20 AND @M_AMT01 <> 0 BEGIN

SET @WORD1 = ( SELECT @WORD1 + MTEXT FROM @INNTBL_01 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT01 )

END

SET @WORD =dbo.NumberToWordsNew(@M_AMT01) + ' Crore '

END

IF @AMOUNT < 10000000 AND @AMOUNT >= 100000 BEGIN

SET @M_AMT01 = @AMOUNT

SELECT @AMOUNT = ( @AMOUNT % 100000 )

SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01-@AMOUNT ) / 100000

SET @WORD1 = ''

IF @M_AMT01 < 100 AND @M_AMT01 > 20 BEGIN

SET @M_AMT02 = @M_AMT01

SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01 % 10)

SET @M_AMT02 = ( @M_AMT02-@M_AMT01 ) / 10

SET @WORD1 = ( SELECT @WORD1 + MTEXT FROM @INNTBL_02 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT02 )

END

IF @M_AMT01 <= 20 AND @M_AMT01 <> 0 BEGIN

SET @WORD1 = ( SELECT @WORD1 + MTEXT FROM @INNTBL_01 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT01 )

END

SET @WORD = @WORD + @WORD1 + 'Lakh '

END

IF @AMOUNT < 100000 AND @AMOUNT >= 1000 BEGIN

SET @M_AMT01 = @AMOUNT

SET @AMOUNT = ( @AMOUNT % 1000 )

SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01-@AMOUNT ) / 1000

SET @WORD1 = ''

IF @M_AMT01 < 100 AND @M_AMT01 > 20 BEGIN

SET @M_AMT02 = @M_AMT01

SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01 % 10 )

SET @M_AMT02 = ( @M_AMT02-@M_AMT01 ) / 10

SET @WORD1 = ( SELECT @WORD1 + MTEXT + '' FROM @INNTBL_02 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT02 )

END

IF @M_AMT01 <= 20 AND @M_AMT01 <> 0 BEGIN

SET @WORD1 = ( SELECT @WORD1 + MTEXT +'' FROM @INNTBL_01 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT01 )

END

SET @WORD = @WORD + @WORD1 + 'Thousand '

END

IF @AMOUNT < 1000 AND @AMOUNT > = 100 BEGIN

SET @M_AMT01 = @AMOUNT

SET @AMOUNT = ( @AMOUNT % 100 )

SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01-@AMOUNT ) / 100

SET @WORD = ( SELECT @WORD + ' ' +MTEXT + 'Hundred ' FROM @INNTBL_01 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT01)

END

IF @AMOUNT < 100 AND @AMOUNT > 20 BEGIN

SET @M_AMT01 = @AMOUNT

SET @AMOUNT = ( @AMOUNT % 10 )

SET @M_AMT01 = ( @M_AMT01-@AMOUNT ) / 10

SET @WORD = ( SELECT @WORD + MTEXT + '' FROM @INNTBL_02 WHERE RECNO = @M_AMT01 )

END

IF @AMOUNT <= 20 AND @AMOUNT >= 1 BEGIN

SET @WORD = ( SELECT @WORD + MTEXT +'' FROM @INNTBL_01 WHERE RECNO = @AMOUNT )

END

--Change
--SET @WORD = @WORD + 'rupees '
SET @WORD = @WORD + ' '

-- STEP 4:

-- CALCULATE THE PAISE ALSO.

DECLARE @WORDP VARCHAR(300)

SET @WORDP = ''

IF @PAISE <> 0 BEGIN

IF @PAISE < 100 AND @PAISE > 20 BEGIN

DECLARE @PAISE_01 VARCHAR(300)

SET @PAISE_01 = @PAISE

SET @PAISE = ( @PAISE % 10 )

SET @PAISE_01 = ( @PAISE_01-@PAISE ) / 10

SET @WORDP = ( SELECT @WORDP + MTEXT FROM @INNTBL_02 WHERE RECNO = @PAISE_01 )

END

IF @PAISE <= 20 AND @PAISE >= 1 BEGIN

SET @WORDP = ( SELECT @WORDP + MTEXT FROM @INNTBL_01 WHERE RECNO = @PAISE )

END

SET @WORD = @WORD + 'and ' + @WORDP + 'paisa'

END

IF @AMOUNT>=1000000000 BEGIN

SET @WORD = ''

END

Return UPPER(@WORD + ' ONLY')

END
```

Comment: Can't you edit your question? Just cut and paste this into your question (And then delete this answer.)